# Copy rows from each Data Validation output

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I am trying to copy and paste as values from cells (B:80:LJ80) on the same sheet from a data validation list of 29 values. The first row it needs to paste in is B32 and then I would like the 2nd output from the string to paste in row B33 etc.

The data validation list is in cell F4.

Is this possible? I have found ways to past values but am having trouble trying to paste entire rows and cycle through to the next row from the next value in the data validation.

Comment: Please include the code you are working on in  your question.

Comment: This question could benefit (*and thus get answered with higher quality and faster*) from some sample data with expected output as well as the code you have with the issues noted